# Load and replaces variables in template strings loaded from a file

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, template-strings

I would like to use ES6 template strings as templates for the translations in my Node.js application.

I have a JSON file `en_GB.json` like this:

```
{
  "app.template": "This is ${foo} I ${bar}",
  "app.foo": "bar"
}
```

In Node I do this:

```
const translations = require('./en_GB.json')
const foo = 'what'
const bar = 'want'

console.log(translations['app.template']) // Outputs This is ${foo} I ${bar}
```

What I want to output is "This is what I want'

Is this possible without using a helper function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/stringinject

https://github.com/tjcafferkey/stringinject

```
var string = stringInject("This is a {0} string for {1}", ["test", "stringInject"]);

// This is a test string for stringInject
```

Comment: No, I need to be able to specify the variables by name. Also I am looking for a native way to do this.

Comment: I have updated my NPM package to allow for this. Is this what you're looking for? https://www.npmjs.com/package/stringinject